# Fastest way to reset MongoDB server / drop all databases

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am starting a test MongoDB server using MongoBox and before each test method I am resetting it:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.purge_database()

    @cached_property
    def mongo_client(self):
        return pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient(host=settings.DEFAULT_DB)

    def purge_database(self, drop=True):
        for db_name in self.mongo_client.database_names():
            db = getattr(self.mongo_client, db_name)
            db.eval("""
                db.getCollectionNames().forEach( function(collection_name) {
                    if (collection_name.indexOf("system.") == -1)
                        db[collection_name].drop();
                    else
                        db.collection_name.remove({});
                });
            """)
```

My tests run too slow :

```
Ran 311 tests in 685.171s
```

This variant

```
def purge_database(self, drop=True):
    for db_name in self.mongo_client.database_names():
        self.mongo_client.drop_database(db_name)
```

is slow too

```
Ran 311 tests in 678.837s
```

And this

```
    # exclude system databases
    database_names = (
        db_name for db_name in
        self.mongo_client.database_names()
        if db_name not in ['local']
    )

    for db_name in database_names:
        db = self.mongo_client[db_name]

        # exclude system collections
        collections = (
            db[c] for c in db.collection_names()
            if not c.startswith('system.')
        )
        for collection in collections:
            if drop:
                db.drop_collection(collection)
            else:
                try:
                    collection.remove(None)
                except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:
                    if collection.options().get('capped', False):
                        # cannot remove documents from capped collections
                        # in latest version of Mongo. Dropping instead.
                        db.drop_collection(collection)
```

too:

```
Ran 311 tests in 657.224s
```

Do you know any other methods to quickly clear the database for each test method?

Comment: Are you sure your system can do better io / cpu wise ? Have you profiled what is the bottleneck ?

Comment: I recently upgraded to MongoDB 3.2.4 from 2.8. Before the tests were taking about 180 second -- about 4 times faster. I don't know what to profile -- the only difference is the new database version.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found at least to fix the regression, is to use `MMAPv1` storage engine in the test database:

```
mongod ... --storageEngine=mmapv1
```

This helped to come back to the original test running times, because the new 3.2 MongoDB version uses WiredTiger storage engine by default, and it's slow for deleting databases/collections.